# Setting a chart source data based on a variable cell range in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am creating a report template part of which will be generating data charts with a structure similar to a moving average

for this I need to select a range of data in one sheet (e.g. `f10:i14`) and place and set it as the source of one chart

The following piece of code works

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Weekly Trends").Range("f10,i14")`

but this does not

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Weekly Trends").Range(Cells(x, y), Cells(k, z))`

it returns a `1004 error`

But I need to specify the range based on variable indices for my report purposes, please help

Comment: [can-variables-be-used-to-select-fully-qualified-range](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/86483-can-variables-used-select-fully-qualified-range.html)? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to fully qualify the `.Cells` object

Try this

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Weekly Trends").Range(Sheets("Weekly Trends").Cells(x, y), Sheets("Weekly Trends").Cells(k, Z))`

You can also make the above code short

```
With Sheets("Weekly Trends")
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(x, y), .Cells(k, Z))
End With
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!
I assumed that qualifying the sheet would be enough.