# How to improve code from macros recorder?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, border

I use this code from macros recorder and add inside a for loop.

How can do better this code if is possible ?

I want use both 2003 and 2010.

```
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address).Select
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .Color = -16777216
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .Color = -16777216
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .Color = -16777216
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
    .LineStyle = xlDouble
    .Color = -16777216
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

Comment: how do you want to make the code better?  what is your problem with the code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179

Comment: To improve it I would say never use select when working with ranges

Comment: @StevenMarciano: Did you see the link that I posted above? :)

Comment: Ah no, sorry I didn't! That is a much more concise answer than mine. Good stuff

Comment: @stormCloud The code is working fine but i think to be smaller

Comment: This is the for loop 'For a = startcol To ((startcol - 1) + (colnumper * objectsnum)) Step colnumper Range(Cells(kefalida, a).Address, Cells(rowsstop, a + (colnumper - 1)).Address).Select'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to my comment above which includes a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select/10718179#10718179) which talks in detail on avoiding `.Select`.

Here are my `three` cents.

**A. Declare your objects/Variables**

It becomes easier to work when you have declared your Variables/objects. This ensures that you do not have to type repetitive code. For example

```
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address).THIS
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address).THAT
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address).THIS

etc...
```

**B. Ensure that you fully qualify your objects and work with them**

This is the most common cause of errors. Consider this line.

```
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address)
```

Here Excel is assuming that you are working with the current sheet. What if you are not. See this example

```
Sheets(2).Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address)
```

Here the `Cells()` object are not fully qualified and can cause an error. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388270/setting-a-chart-source-data-based-on-a-variable-cell-range-in-vba)

**C. Cut out the extra/repetitive code**

The Excel constants `xlEdgeLeft`, `xlEdgeTop`, `xlEdgeBottom`, `xlEdgeRight` etc each is equal to a number and that too in increasing order. If you type it in Immediate window then you can check it's value

```
'~~> This will give you 7
?xlEdgeLeft
```

So we can actually take advantage of this and shorten out code.

See the code below

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 2).Address, .Cells(5, 5).Address)

        With rng
            .Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
            .Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone

            For i = 7 To 10
                'xlEdgeLeft = 7 : xlEdgeTop = 8 : xlEdgeBottom = 9
                'xlEdgeRight = 10
                With .Borders(i)
                    .LineStyle = xlDouble: .Color = -16777216: .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            Next

            For i = 11 To 12
                'xlInsideVertical = 11 : xlInsideHorizontal = 12
                With .Borders(i)
                    .LineStyle = xlContinuous: _
                    .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic: .Weight = xlThick
                End With
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would also mention "Avoid using the `.Select` method" (which you are already doing)

Comment: Barry, I already did that :) See the link in the comments below the question

Comment: However point taken and I will add that in my post above as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the range like this

```
Range(Cells(2, 2).Address, Cells(5, 5).Address).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlDouble
```

Do this for each border edge and colour etc